# Sound does not stop after calling stop() and release() android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, release

I have an activity that loops a simple song during a score screen depending on whether a player won or lost in my game. However, after exiting my Score Activity, the sound continues to loop until garbage collection occurs. Below are the snippets of my code. I currently force garbage collection to stop the sound! Why doesn't stop() or release() work?

```java
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    _sounds.release();
}

public void load(){
    _victory = MediaPlayer.create(mActivity, R.raw.victory);
    _victory.setLooping(true);

    _failure = MediaPlayer.create(mActivity, R.raw.flutedeath);
    _failure.setLooping(true);
}

public void release(){
    _victory.stop();
    _victory.release();
    _victory = null;

    _failure.stop();
    _failure.release();
    _failure = null;
    System.gc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a OnCompletionListener something like this:

```
      try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, fileId);
            mp.start();

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }
```

Comment: Your suggestion works if MediaPlayer is not looping. However, on my Samsung Galaxy SII, the sound continues to loop as before, despite stop() and release().